# Why does my dev minion have access to prod pillar data?

Tags: salt-stack

I am new to Salt. I have created a test environment with a master and one minion. I put information about a simple app in each of three pillars: base, dev and prod.

The minion is assigned to the "dev" environment so I expected it to see only "dev" and "base" pillars but it has access to everything. Isn't the environment supposed to control which states and which pillar data is available to the minions?

## cat /etc/salt/master

```
root_dir: /
autosign_file: /etc/salt/autosign.conf
file_roots:
  base:
    - /data/salt/states
  dev:
    - /data/salt/states/dev
  prod:
    - /data/salt/states/prod
pillar_roots:
  base:
    - /data/salt/pillar/base
  dev:
    - /data/salt/pillar/dev
  prod:
    - /data/salt/pillar/prod
```

## cat /data/salt/pillar/base/top.sls

```
  '*':
    - baseapp
```

## cat /data/salt/pillar/dev/top.sls

```
  '*':
    - devapp
```

## cat /data/salt/pillar/prod/top.sls

```
  '*':
    - prodapp
```

From minion:

## salt-call grains.get environment

```
    dev
```

## salt-call pillar.items

```
    ----------
    baseapp:
        ----------
        listen-on:
            any
        name:
            base_app_config
        port:
            154
    devapp:
        ----------
        listen-on:
            any
        name:
            dev_app_config
        port:
            155
    prodapp:
        ----------
        listen-on:
            any
        name:
            prod_app_config
        port:
            153
```

I did not expect the dev minion to have access to prod pillar data. I hoped that making changes to files in states/prod and pillar/prod would never impact dev servers and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The minion is assigned to the "dev" environment

[Environment settings on the minion](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/master/ref/configuration/minion.html#saltenv) only set the default when none is specified. They can request data for any environment they want.

The default value of [`top_file_merging_strategy`](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/master/ref/configuration/master.html#top-file-merging-strategy) is `merge`. This gives you a final topfile of:

```yaml
'*':
  - baseapp
  - devapp
  - prodapp
```

That assigns all three pillars to every minion.

To restrict pillar data to specific minions, you need to use the top file to target them, ideally by their minion id:

```yaml
base:
  '*':
    - baseapp

prod:
  'prod-*':
    - prodapp

dev:
  '.*-(dev|test)$':
    - match: pcre
    - devapp
```

---

I note that you have autosign configured, which unless you are careful means you cannot even trust a minion's id, and attackers may be able to exfiltrate any of your pillar secrets.